# Unable to remove symbol from mac menu bar

Tags: macos, mac, menu-bar

I have the symbol from the trend micro security agent in my menu bar and can't remove it. I tried to remove it via command + drag into the bin and also closing it in the activity monitor app didn't help. I also don't have any other folders or apps from trend micro on my mac anymore. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Things that need an installer generally also need an uninstaller. Antivirus suites especially, as they are designed to prevent circumvention.

See https://helpcenter.trendmicro.com/en-us/article/tmka-14475 for the uninstaller.

Comment: Thanks :) Tried it, but didn't help :(

Comment: Are you certain you got the correct uninstaller for your actual product? Home vs business versions require different processes. You didn't say which you have. Also, sometimes if you've attempted to pick this apart manually & failed, you need to fully re-install before the uninstaller will function correctly.

Comment: I have now tried the uninstaller for home and business but both are not working :( Is there any other option?

Comment: You're probably down to asking Trend Micro for assistance with their product. They will probably need to know precise details of product, version, etc